# Sveltekit javascript playground with iFrame

Tags: javascript, sveltekit

Our aim is  to enable users write scripts on their end as discussed [here](https://blog.bitsrc.io/build-an-html-css-js-playground-64c62133746d). Tried to include script tag in `iFrame.writeIn` but it errs when included :

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { onMount } from "svelte";
import { testjson } from "$src/stores/store1";

// let root;

onMount(async () => {
  const getEl = id => document.getElementById(id)

  const iFrame = getEl('iFrame').contentWindow.document
const htmlTextArea = getEl('htmlTextarea')
const cssTextArea = getEl('cssTextarea')
const jsTextArea = getEl('jsTextarea')

document.body.onkeyup = function() {
    iFrame.open()
    iFrame.writeln(
        htmlTextArea.value +
        '<style>' +
        cssTextArea.value +
        '</style>' 
        +
        '<script>' +
        jsTextArea.value +
        '</script>'
    )
    iFrame.close()
}

})

</script>
```

When edited  `'<script>' + jsTextArea.value + '</script>'` from javascript as  etc (anything other than , not getting error but it doesn't run scripts.

Then HTML is like this:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
      <h3>HTML/CSS/JS Playground</h3>
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
              <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#html" data-toggle="tab"> HTML</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#css" data-toggle="tab">CSS</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#js" data-toggle="tab">JS</a></li>
              </ul>
              <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
                  <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="html">
                      <p>
                          <textarea style="float:left" id="htmlTextarea"></textarea>
                      </p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="css">
                      <p>
                          <textarea style="float:left" id="cssTextarea"></textarea>
                      </p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="js">
                      <p>
                          <textarea style="float:left" id="jsTextarea"></textarea>
                      </p>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12">
              <div>
                  <iframe id="iFrame"></iframe>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>

  </div>

</body>
```

Think there is a security config which hinders writing scripts on sveltekit. How can we enable users to write scripts on their end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found after posting. Sveltekit doesn't allow script tag inside of script. So put it inside of textarea with `on:change` function. Please see below:

```
` <div class="tab-pane fade" id="js">
     <p>
   <textarea on:change={() => iFrame.writeln(
                  
       `<script>` +
         jsTextArea.value +
               `</script>`
     )} style="float:left" id="jsTextarea"></textarea>
        </p>
    </div>`
```